# SQL - count conversations in messenger

Tags: sql, count

There is messenger_table that stores information about every message ever sent in a messenger.

- message_id
- message_date
- message_time
- message_sender_id
- message_receiver_id

I'm trying to construct a query that returns number of conversations between users. Here is my SQL code:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT sender, receiver)
   - COUNT(DISTINCT receiver, sender) AS count_dialogues 
FROM messenger_table
```

Can you recommend better ways to count number of conversations?

As an example we look at any popular messenger.
Every message belongs to 1 conversation. Any conversation has from 1 to many messages and lasts constantly. Two users have only one conversation. When Alice texts Bob and Bob replies to Alice, we count it as a single conversation.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  Please define "conversation".  Your table has "messages".

Comment: Make it easy, and possible, to assist you: [mcve].